# Bash script not running in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell

I'm getting started with bash scripting and made this little script following along a short guide but for some reason when I run the script with `sh myscript` I get

```
myscript: 5: myscript: 0: not found running on ubuntu 12.04
```

here is my script below I should at least see the echo message if no args are set:

```
#!/bin/bash
#will do something

name=$1
username=$2
if (( $# == 0 ))
then
    echo "##############################"
    echo "myscript [arg1] [arg2]"
    echo "arg1 is your name"
    echo "and arg2 is your username"
fi

var1="Your name is ${name} and your username is ${username}"

`echo ${var1} > yourname.txt`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
`echo ${var1} > yourname.txt`
```

Get rid of the backticks.

```
echo ${var1} > yourname.txt
```

---

> ...for some reason when I run the script with `sh myscript`...

Don't run it that way. Make the script executable and run it directly

```
chmod +x myscript
./script
```

(or run with `bash myscript` explicitly).

Comment: The problem with the backticks is that they run the command and then the shell tries to run the *output* from that command as a command again. And `sh` is not `bash`. You should always use what you mean.

Comment: Thank you that works, as long as I run with ./ in front but if I just call it with myscript I get command not found but I can figure that out.

Comment: @A.Bal Without a path (and `./` is a path) the shell does a `$PATH` lookup for the name `myscript` and can't find it. If you want that to work you need to put it in a directory in your `$PATH` (or add a directory to your `$PATH` and put it in there).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that expression will work in bash but not in sh.  As others pointed out change it to executable, make sure your shebang line is using bash and run it like this:

```
./myscript
```

If you want to run it with sh then it is complaining about line 5.  Change it to this and it will work in /bin/sh.

```
if [ $# -ne 0 ]
```

Check out the man page for test.

Also you don't need the backticks on this line: 
    echo ${var1} > yourname.txt

Comment: `(( $# == 0 ))` is perfectly valid shell test (try it). It is an arithmetic expression.

Comment: Yeah.. I tried it on the command line and it does work.  I was able to replicate his error and I knew the other expression would work.  Which is why I said I thought that was going on.   I'd love to know what is happening there for myself as well.

Comment: Ok.. I see what's happening.  That error only occurs if you run it with the /bin/sh shell.  Running it with bash it works perfectly.   Updating my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Right, `sh` is not `bash`.

Comment: But seems to be what OP is doing: "when I run the script with `sh myscript`"

Comment: @Etan is correct.  He should run it with the shell he is coding for .

Comment: If using `sh` was a requirement then replacing the arithmetic expression would be correct. Since that wasn't indicated (and the shebang indicated otherwise) while it works it isn't the main problem with correct execution of the script.